# How to import dll functions (DllInstall()) in order to be able to register it using regsvr32?

Tags: c#, dll, regsvr32

The idea is:
- i am trying to write a dll (i'm using the class library (.net framework) in Visual Studio 2019;
-i want to register it, using regsvr32;
-i get the following error when trying to register it: exemple.dll was loaded but the entry point dllInstall() was not found;

I need an explanation on what i need to add to my dll (there is a class with a method that does some decoding) in order to be able to register it.

Comment: You don't use regsvr32 with .NET DLLs. It's even a [FAQ](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/csharpfaq/what-is-the-equivalent-to-regsvr32-in-net/) on a MS website.

Comment: Are you planning to use your dll in c++, VBScript, VB6, Delphi, or some old COM enabled language? If not, do yourself a favour and learn more interesting technologies.